# Enviar array javascript a backend C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, aspx

Desde javascript voy a enviar lo siguiente por ajax

```
var json = "{'archivoId':'" + archivoId + "','filter':'" + filter + "'}";
```

'filter' es un array, pero tiene que llegar a un metodo C# que tiene la siguiente firma

```
 public static RespuestaArchivo ObtenerArchivoZip(int archivoId, string[] filter = null){


 }
```

El problema es que 'filter' llega como tipo object y el me está  diciendo lo siguiente "No se puede convertir el objeto de tipo 'System.String' en el tipo 'System.String[]'". Cambiar la firma del método en C# es demasiado complejo y largo por lo que tiene ese método actualmente. Como puedo parsearlo para que lo reconozca C#?.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo haces tu llamada Ajax para enviar los datos al *backend*? Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que formas para `filter` es el detalle; ya que tienes:

```
var json = "{..., 'filter':'" + filter + "'}";
```

así especificas que es un texto lo que envías.

si el `filter`que envias (**" + filter +"**) es un array te falta tratarlo como corresponde y cambiar el `json`; prueba de la siguiente manera (asumo `filter`es un array):

```
var json = "{..., 'filter':['" + filter.join('\', \'') + "']}";
```

Comment: ¿Porqué encierras los elementos del `array` entre comillas simples? Si fuesen valores tipo `number` les estás cambiando el tipo, ¿y si son objetos?. Mejor sólo separarlos por comas. Ahora, lo que veo en la pregunta del OP, es que su variable `json` es simplemente una cadena. Si la llamada es por Ajax, porqué no enviar un Objeto de Javascript y dejar que el parser de Ajax lo convierta a JSON. Me temo que el OP tiene algún tipo de duda o confusión. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @MauricioContreras de la forma en que lo puse se asegura que sea `string[]` lo que se envía tal cual el procedimiento que lo recibirá para el caso que ocupa la respuesta que dí.